# WordPress Plugin Development - How to re-upload/update plugin while developing, without deleting current version?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, upload, updates

I just started developing plugins for WordPress (fun!) and am curious if there is a faster/better way to upload a new version of the plugin, without having to delete the current one first?

I am not using the WordPress.org Developer Center, as the plugin I am making will be strictly for internal purposes. I am just uploading the plugin folder (zipped) through the WP Plugin Dashboard.

Since I am new to developing plugins, I am doing a lot of testing and frequent updating of the code. Would be nice if I could save time with the whole delete-then-reinstall-and-activate process.

Comment: Simply replace the files via ftp and refresh your browser. No need to deactivate. Also, consider doing plugin development locally with MAMP or the like, so you can edit the files directly on your computer. It'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: @diggy Thanks! Yeah I think that is the easiest solution, I just didn't have FTP setup on all machines I work on. Will probably just do that.

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

1. Sync files with git, possibly on pushing to a central repo - that's what I use daily.
2. rsync (run manually when needed)
3. Some people are using capistrano or something similar, but I personally think that this is not necessary if you're making frequent changes in a staging environment.